# How would investing in real estate (REIT or similar) affect my tax situation in the U.S.?

Tags: united-states, real-estate, state-income-tax, florida, singapore

My wife and I are in our 30s and bought our first house this past year.  We don't expect to have enough money to buy a rental property or another house in the foreseeable future, but we are considering investing in other real estate as a way to grow our wealth and potentially pay off our house faster.  We have a fairly good emergency fund and retirement accounts.

So far, a REIT or something similar sounds appealing to us.  Compared to rental properties, these would apparently create less work for us and require a smaller initial investment.  I've been looking at a range of REIT providers (including crowdfunding companies) like Fundrise, DiversyFund, Wealthfront, and Vanguard.

In the 2010s, my dad invested in an oil pipeline. Because it physically went through dozens of states, he had to file taxes for every single state where it was.  This kept him busy all tax season long for several years (he files his own taxes) until he was able to finally sell the investment at a gain.

We are trying to start investing while avoiding getting us in the same situation he was in.  We file our own taxes, too, and so far our tax situation has been pretty manageable.

What do we need to know from a tax standpoint about real estate investing in order to keep our tax situation under control?

We live in Florida.  If we restrict ourselves to properties or REITs located in Florida, can we avoid needing to file in other states?  Do we need to restrict ourselves like this?

In case it's also relevant: I am a US citizen, and my wife is a Singaporean with a US green card.

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue with your father's oil investment was, but an REIT is just a corporation whose business is owning and managing real estate. When you buy Apple stock, you don't have to pay taxes in all the states where Apple does business. And when you buy an REIT you don't have to pay taxes in all the states where that REIT does business.

Comment: However it's not 100% clear to me whether Fundrise and DiversyFund are actually REITs or some other kind of structure, so I'll leave that aspect of the question for someone else to answer.

Comment: @ThePhoton If I'm interpreting their websites correctly, it looks like Fundrise and DiversyFund both treat a single investment as an investment in a portfolio of diversified real estate assets.  It's like how in my retirement accounts (401k and 403b), when I have contributed a certain amount each month, it actually went to an index fund or portfolio of stocks/bonds/etc. instead of to just "my 401k" or "my 403b".

Comment: I read a bit more of the websites. At one point Diversy calls itself an "eREIT", whatever that is. In a FAQ  about taxes, Fundrise says that some of their investments are REITs that send 1099DIVs, and others send 1K tax forms, which report on partnerships. Investing in a partnership is where you might have to start worrying about state taxes. Also liability and other risks.

Comment: Overall those two websites are so heavy on marketing blather and light on important details that I am not in the least tempted to invest.

Comment: @ThePhoton: I think the reason they have hype and no information is that they aren't allowed to market to non-accredited investors.  Hype (which generates leads not sales) evidently doesn't fall afoul of the regulations the same way that actual data would.  Presumably they have a much more factual sales pitch when following up on a lead, after eliminating non-accredited investors.  Of course the accreditation requirements means that they can't be used by OP if I'm correctly understanding "We don't expect to have enough money to buy a rental property or another house in the foreseeable future"

Comment: @BenVoigt, the DiversyFund site says "We’re taking real estate investing to the next level by opening up private REIT investments to all investors (accredited or not) from one simple platform." The Fundrise site says "Regardless of your net worth, you can now benefit from real estate’s unique potential for generating consistent cash flow and long-term appreciation. This is a level of real estate investing that was previously reserved for only the wealthiest investors and institutions." So both seem to be saying they are open to non-accredited investors.